# ClassNotFoundException, /mnt/asec

Tags: android, android-manifest, classnotfoundexception

I´ve recently imported a project I knew was working before into Eclipse. After I try to install the project it says

```
09-13 11:55:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(7880): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cz.ursimon.heureka.client.android.prj.heureka.activity.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/cz.ursimon.heureka.client.android-1/pkg.apk]
```

but I can´t find out what the problem is. First I thought it is the common problem with new ADT update, but I tried checking the PrivateLibraries in Order and Export according to other solutions, I cleaned my project several times and I can´t see anything wrong in my `AndroidManifest` file.

Anyone with a solution? :S

[image: Project packages]

My AndroidManifest file:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cz.ursimon.heureka.client.android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="26062"
    android:versionName="3.0"    
     >
   <activity
   android:name=".prj.heureka.activity.MainActivity"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Comment: It may be because of the libraries you have added recently in your application. I just faced this sought of issue yesterday and i resolved it after removing the library and again adding it.

Comment: Can you please show us your project explorer. You just make sure whether you have the package name "cz.ursimon.heureka.client.android.prj.heureka.activity.MainActivity". If this was not the problem then try to remove "android:installLocation="preferExternal" from you manifest file and test.

Comment: the class is really there. it worked before. if i remove preferExternal property, it throws the same error, except it doesnt look for the Class in /mnt/asec/cz.ursimon.heureka.client.android-1/pkg.apk, but in /data/app/...   why is it even trying to find it in the /mnt/asec/ path? i think that has never happened before

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export` and ensure Android Private Libraries are checked for your project and for all other library projects you are using.

Clean all projects afterwards and Run your project

Comment: I am sure it is checked. It did not help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file define the whole class path of your activity as below for your activity.
Also make sure your package defined is correct and in that pacakge your MainAcivity class resides.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cz.ursimon.heureka.client.android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="26062"
    android:versionName="3.0"    
    >

    <activity
        android:name="cz.ursimon.heureka.client.android.prj.heureka.activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">   

</manifest>
```